# Decreasing the distance between heading h1 and border?

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to decrease the distance between the text in the h1 element and the border to the right so it looks like a small vertical line which separates it from the following text.

This is what my current css looks like:

```
.test{
   border-right: 2px solid black;
   padding-right: 0px;
}
```

The right border still appears very far on the right although I thought through setting the padding to 0px at the right it should appear directly next to the text.

I guess this is a pretty dumb question, I am still a beginner!

Thanks in advance

Comment: try changing the width of the `h1`.

Comment: Even though you may think its a dumb question, at least you asked it appropriately.  I just wanted to vent.  Some of this stuff today

Answer (score 3):

`h1` elements are `display: block` by default (with `width: 100%`), which means they stretch to the full width of their container.

If you want to have the element only be as wide as it needs to be, make it `display: inline-block` instead (and then use padding, as you've identified, to determine the distance between the end of the text and the right border):

```css
.test{
   border-right: 2px solid black;
   padding-right: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="test">This is a test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

h1 elements are `display:block` by default, 100% width by default. Try changing `width:300px` or `display:inline-block`.